# How to add column names in for loop based on quartile division?

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame as follows:

```
data = {
    'Name': ['tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'ram', 'antony', 'nicols',
             'lisa', 'sasha', 'jynx', 'dani'],
    'Cricket': [8, 9, 11, 6, 12, 15, 14, 12, 11, 13, 7],
    'Football': [1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 0, 5, 4, 6],
    'Hockey': [1, 0, 1, 0, 5, 6, 12, 12, 14, 13, 10],
    'Soccer': [5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 11, 12],
    'Kabadi': [9, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

It looks as follows:

```
    Name    Cricket Football    Hockey  Soccer  Kabadi
0   tom     8       1           1       5       9
1   nick    9       3           0       6       4
2   krish   11      1           1       2       5
3   jack    6       3           0       9       3
4   ram     12      5           5       5       3
5   antony  15      6           6       5       4
6   nicols  14      2           12      6       5
7   lisa    12      0           12      7       6
8   sasha   11      5           14      6       6
9   jynx    13      4           13      11      6
10  dani    7       6           10      12      7
```

I want add to a new group column for each column in df based on quartile cut-off in for loop.

```
df['Cricket'].quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75])

0.10     7.0
0.25     8.5
0.50    11.0
0.75    12.5
Name: Cricket, dtype: float64
```

#Grouping Low, Moderate and High

```
conditions = [
    (df['Cricket'] >= 12.5),
    (df['Cricket'] < 12.5) & (df['Cricket'] >= 8.5),
    (df['Cricket'] < 8.5)
    ]
values = ['High','Moderate', 'Low']
df['CricketGroup'] = np.select(conditions, values)
df.head()
```

The data looks as follows:

```
    Name    Cricket Football    Hockey  Soccer  Kabadi  CricketGroup
0   tom     8       1           1       5       9       Low
1   nick    9       3           0       6       4       Moderate
2   krish   11      1           1       2       5       Moderate
3   jack    6       3           0       9       3       Low
4   ram     12      5           5       5       3       Moderate
```

How can perform this in a for loop where I need to add columns for `FootballGroup`, `HockeyGroup`, ..., `KabadiGroup` based on quartile cut-off?

Comment: How do you handle Soccer where `.1` and `.25` are both `5`?

Comment: `for col in ('Cricket','Football','Hockey','Soccer','Kabadi'):` / `newcol = col + 'Group'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if possible [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
f1 = lambda x: pd.qcut(x, [.1, .25, .5, .75], 
                       labels=['Low','Moderate', 'High']).fillna('Low')
```

Your function should be changed by compared values from `Series`:

```
def f1(x):
    s = x.quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75])
    conditions = [
    (x >= s[0.75]),
    (x < s[0.75]) & (x >= s[0.5]),
    (x < s[0.5])
    ]
    values = ['High','Moderate', 'Low']
    return np.select(conditions, values)

#apply only for columns from list
cols = ['Cricket','Football','Hockey','Soccer','Kabadi']

df1 = df[cols].apply(f1).add_suffix('Group')

df = df.join(df1)
```

Comment: I get following error 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @user288925 - There is multiple columns filled by strings like `Name` column?

Comment: is it possible to round the quartile value. for example `10. 8` to `10` or `11.2` to `11` or `0.965` to `0.9`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 'Cricket  Football  Hockey  Soccer  Kabadi'.split():

    #i='Cricket'
    q=df[i].quantile([.1, .25, .5, .75])
    
    conditions = [
        (df[i] >= q[0.75]),
        (df[i] < q[0.75]) & (df[i] >= q[0.25]),
        (df[i] < q[0.25])
        ]
    values = ['High','Moderate', 'Low']
    grname=i+'Group'
    df[grname] = np.select(conditions, values)
    df[[i,grname]] #check
```

Comment: where 'Cricket  Football  Hockey  Soccer  Kabadi'.split() is :
['Cricket', 'Football', 'Hockey', 'Soccer', 'Kabadi']

it bothers to write literally ['Cricket', 'Football', 'Hockey', 'Soccer', 'Kabadi'] ...

Comment: This will use Cricket's quantiles for all columns because the bounds in `conditions` are hard coded.

Comment: @HenryEcker thank you! i edited my code, by making new variable q